# Simple casting in Kotlin/Java

Tags: kotlin, casting

I have an object `User` defined as below

```
class User(){
    var id: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null}
```

For certain reasons, I have to create new object `User` of same parameters and I have to copy data from old to new type.

```
class UserNew(){
    var id: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null}
```

I was looking for easiest way to convert from old type to a new one. I want to do simply

```
var user = User()
var userNew = user as UserNew
```

But obviously, I am getting `This cast can never succeed`. Creating a new `UserNew` object and set every parameter is not feasible if I have a `User` object with lots of parameters. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is UserNew?

Comment: Oh, just edited.

Comment: just make a constructor in UserNew taking a User as a parameter. Problem solved.

Comment: @jwenting well, as I said that's not feasible if I have really lots of fields in `User` object

Comment: Use a tool like http://modelmapper.org/

Comment: @MusoKhon that's excuse. A constructor is the way to do this, the only way, unless you're making UserNew a subclass of User.

Comment: Are the member variables going to be same for both the class, in that case can you define your use case why you want to have a different class.

Comment: @MusoKhon you could also have a UserNew contain a User directly as well as any extra fields.  Other than that, there is literally no way around copying the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve you can Simply use Gson and avoid boilerplate code:

```
var user = User(....)

val json = Gson().toJson(user)

val userNew:UserNew =Gson().fromJson(json, UserNew::class.java)
```

Answer (score 4):

`as` is kotlin's cast operator. But `User` is not a `UserNew`. Therefore the cast fails.

Use an extension function to convert between the types:

```
fun User.toUserNew(): UserNew {
    val userNew = UserNew()
    userNew.id = id
    userNew.name = name
    return userNew
}
```

And use it like so

```
fun usingScenario(user: User) {
    val userNew = user.toUserNew()
```

Comment: i implemented your answer in below answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this way is not feasible if I have lets say 50 fields instead of 2 (id and name). As most of people suggest, this is the only solution I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write a boilerplate code, you can use some libraries that will copy values via reflection (for example http://mapstruct.org/), but it's not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

you should follow this logic for this case.
 note: @Frank Neblung answer i implemented

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val user = User()
user.id = 10
user.name = "test"
var userNew = user.toUserNew()
println(userNew.id) // output is 10
println(userNew.name)// output is test
 }


class User() 
{
var id: Int? = null
var name: String? = null

fun toUserNew(): UserNew {
    val userNew = UserNew()
    userNew.id = id
    userNew.name = name
    return userNew
  }
}

  class UserNew() {
  var id: Int? = null
  var name: String? = null
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either create interface and implement it in both classes. then you can use this interface in both places (User,UserNew) If this is not what you want, i would use copy constructor in UserNew taking User as parameter, You can create new

`NewUser nu = new UserNew(userOld)`

if you have lots of properties answer from ppressives is way to go

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can use the concept of inheritance:

https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/inheritance

Example:

```
open class Person(age: Int) {
// code for eating, talking, walking
}

class MathTeacher(age: Int): Person(age) {
// other features of math teacher
}
```